# Access custom component props and URL parameters from react-router-dom in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a route in `react-router-dom` set up like this:

```
<Route path="/result/:result" component={ResultsView} audio={audio} speechRecognition={speechRecognition} />
```

And a component with typed props like this:

```
interface ResultsViewProps {
  audio: HTMLAudioElement;
  speechRecognition: Types.SpeechRecognition;
}
interface ResultsViewRouterParams {
  result: string;
}
interface ResultsViewState {
  ...
}

export default class ResultsView extends React.Component<
ResultsViewProps & RouteComponentProps<ResultsViewRouterParams>,
ResultsViewState
> {
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I'm getting a `:result` parameter from the URL, which I want to pass to ResultsView. At the same time, I also want to pass the custom props `audio` and `speechRecognition` to the same component. Unfortunately, I'm stuck here. I've just recently migrated this project to TypeScript (from pure JS). Previously the above way worked, now TypeScript obviously complains that "Route" doesn't have those custom props. I've tried several ways to instead of simply passing "ResultsView" as the component to the Route, to pass a component with the custom props included, etc., but all those ways didn't work either.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `element=` instead of `component=` here: `<Route path="/result/:result" component={ResultsView}...`?

Comment: Never mind, I should have asked instead what version of **react-router-dom** do you use?

Comment: @tromgy My bad, should have added that. Using the latest v5, so 5.3.0.

Comment: Yes, I see. What I was going to propose is not going to work with that, but just in case if you upgrade to v6, you can use this syntax to pass properties to the route target component: `<Route path="/mypath", element={<MyTargetComponent prop={value}/>}/>`

Comment: @tromgy Yep, that's what I've originally tried with the `component` prop, but guess that doesn't work in v5. Since I'm also still using React 16.7 and class components, I'd rather not update to v6 (since v6 makes heavy use of hooks it seems). I'll first see if someone comes along with a solution for v5. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. When using react-router-dom v5, it's possible to use the render property instead of component to pass in the props for the child component. In my case, this looks like the following:

```
<Route
  path="/result/:result"
  render={(props) => <ResultsView audio={audio} speechRecognition={speechRecognition} {...props} />}
/>
```

I also simplified the typing of the components props like so:

```
interface ResultsViewProps extends RouteComponentProps<ResultsViewRouterParams> {
  audio: HTMLAudioElement;
  speechRecognition: Types.SpeechRecognition;
}
interface ResultsViewRouterParams {
  result: string;
}
interface ResultsViewState {
  ...
}

export default class ResultsView extends React.Component<ResultsViewProps, ResultsViewState> {
  ...
}
```

Inside the component, it's then possible to read the param through `this.props.match.params.result`.